# TListView in virtual mode limited to 100,000,000 items?

Tags: windows, delphi, listview, windows-7, delphi-xe4

Setting Items.Count in a ListView to any number over 100,000,000 has the same result as setting the count to 0 - is this a limitation of the underlying windows control, or Delphi specific? I expected the limit to be ~2 billion, since Delphi XE4's documentation says the limit is the size of a (signed) DWORD (ie: 2^31 - 1).

Simple Example:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    procedure ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Assumes ListView1.OwnerData := True;
  ListView1.Items.Count := 100000001; // Works if 100000000 is used instead
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.Caption := Item.Index.ToString();
end;

end.
```

I did some poking around, sending LVM_SETITEMCOUNT directly to the underlying control, but it returns an error with any LPARAM over 100,000,000 and sets the internal count to 0, leading me to believe it's a limitation of the underlying control. I can't find this documented anywhere - although I assume that having that many items isn't common. Assuming this is a limitation of the control, should probably file a Delphi bug report since no exception gets thrown by TListView when the call fails - it just breaks everything silently.

For now, I'm working around this by keeping the listview out of virtual mode, keeping exactly the number of items that are visible depending on the size of the control (ie: VisibleRowCount property) added to the list, maintaining an offset into my data, and looping over the items in the list to fill the list in essentially the same way as a virtual mode list, using my own scrollbar to control the offset to actually make the limit ~2 billion.

Is there a way around this behavior? Any insight from anyone experienced with working with large amounts of data and a ListView?

Comment: why not VirtualTreeView in listview mode ?

Comment: I've tried experimenting with VirtualTreeView, but lack experience in using it properly - while it is fast, from what I've done so far it allocates a small structure for each item in the list, so I ran into memory issues around the 40 million item mark. Links to tutorials in using it so that it functions like a virtual listview?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/borland.public.cppbuilder.vcl.components.using/-tWP7HwrRjA

Comment: Can you provide a link to the docs that says 2^31 is supported?

Comment: Thanks David - guess I was right about this being an underlying OS limitation. Now to find a nice solution for displaying; my current workaround -works- which is the important thing, but I feel it's a bit kludgy having a fixed size non-virtual listview hacked so that each item gets updated dynamically from a separate scrollbar. But hey, it works with my largest set of data so far at 274,000,000 entries and around the same speed as a real virtual listview, so I can't -really- complain.

Comment: Set OwnerData to true to specify that the list view is virtual. A virtual list view can contain a huge number of items (specifically, up to a DWORD). [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView.OwnerData) The documentation implies 2^32, but 2^31 in actuality because the type actually used is a signed type.

Comment: Looks like Embarcadero help file screwed up yet again...

Comment: That documentation is plain wrong.

Comment: @Chrisgbk:  Just curious:  how would the user navigate a listview with 10^8 items in it?

Comment: What about using some pagination?

Comment: @MartynA In my specific case, I'm using the report view with multiple columns so it's essentially a (very) long list of items that's scrolled with a scrollbar. Or searched through with a find routine.

Comment: @Chrisgbk: Ah, ok.  I'd use a Devex grid for that sort of situation ...

Comment: @Chrisgbk A scrollbar is no use here because it has resolution of only one pixel. Assume a vertical scrollbar height of 1000px (a large estimate), then each notch on your scroll bar covers 100,000 items. So the user is going to have to find. In which case I'd probably force them to type in a search filter, and then show hits in a list view.

Comment: True; but look at my own answer that shows my workaround - I override OnScroll to do my own processing to support the resolution needed. Using the arrows scrolls by 1, using Page Up/Down scrolls by one page of items, and the actual position of the thumb is calculated. Even with 2^63-1 items, I can scroll using a scrollbar with only a min and max of 0 and 100 respectively, but still be able to use the scrollbar to access every single item. Note that that doesn't mean it's limited to the keyboard keys - clicking the arrows, or the space between the thumb and arrow, counts the same.

Comment: Not in a useful way. You might need to scroll through a million pages or more to find what you want. Such amounts of data don't fit into scrolling idiom. If I were you, I'd take a different approach altogether. Very interesting UX problem.

Comment: I'll be specific about what my specific use was: a very quick and simple hex viewer for binary files. I ran into the problem on files greater than ~1.6GB because, default layout of 16 bytes per row with the max rows of virtual ListView :) This particular use very much suits the scrolling idiom, despite the extremely large data set, but of course, needs ancillary functionality to be useful, like search results for patterns and such in a window that let you jump to a specific point.

Comment: OK, that makes a bit more sense to me. Frankly I think I'd go for a complete custom control for that, rather than squeezing sense out of a list view. Very interesting. I enjoyed this question!

Comment: This issue has been known to the VCL community since at least 2004, and has existed since at least Windows 98: [virtual listview with MORE than 100 million items does not show anything anymore](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/borland.public.cppbuilder.vcl.components.using/-tWP7HwrRjA)

Comment: Thanks Remy, but David already beat you to that exact thread link :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed appear a limitation of the underlying control. You will need to either change your UI design to avoid the limit, or find a different control. That said, I doubt that there are many controls that can usefully display 100 million items.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer, since it answers the main question. I've added my own answer to show my workaround.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my new workaround, it increases the maximum items a virtual ListView can display to 9223372036854775807 (2^63 - 1), in case it is useful to anyone. Think of it as a virtual-virtual ListView. With some work it may be possible to extend it to work with all views, not just list or detailed.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Math;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    ScrollBar1: TScrollBar;
    procedure ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
    procedure ListView1Resize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ScrollBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ScrollBar1Scroll(Sender: TObject; ScrollCode: TScrollCode;
      var ScrollPos: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Offset: Int64;
    ItemCount: Int64;
    VisibleItems: Integer;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

// Assumptions:
// ListView1.OwnerData := True
// ListView1.ViewStyle := vsReport with columns set up OR vsList
// ScrollBar1.Min := 0;
// 
// The position of the scrollbar represents equally spaced points along the data
// You can increase this to any number the scrollbar supports
// By default, that means 101 points (0-100), from offset 0 to (ItemCount - VisibleItems + 1)

const
  LISTVIEW_VIRTUALITEMS_MAX = 100000000;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ItemCount := High(Int64); // For testing
  // Make sure the listview shows enough items
  ListView1.Items.Count := Min(ItemCount, LISTVIEW_VIRTUALITEMS_MAX);
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
var
  Index: Int64;
begin
  // Item.Index now represents an offset from an offset, adding them together
  // gives the true index
  Index := Offset + Item.Index;
  Item.Caption := Index.ToString; // Testing
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VisibleItems := ListView1.VisibleRowCount;
  if VisibleItems = 0 then VisibleItems := 1;
  ListView1.Items.Count := VisibleItems;
end;

procedure TForm1.ScrollBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.Refresh;
end;

procedure TForm1.ScrollBar1Scroll(Sender: TObject; ScrollCode: TScrollCode;
  var ScrollPos: Integer);
  var
  MaxOffset: Int64;
begin
  // Int64 support for scrollbar, etc
  MaxOffset := ItemCount - VisibleItems + 1;
  case ScrollCode of
    TScrollCode.scLineUp: begin
      if Offset > 0 then
        Offset := Offset - 1;
    end;
    TScrollCode.scLineDown: begin
      if Offset < MaxOffset then
        Offset := Offset + 1;
    end;
    scPageUp: begin
      if Offset > VisibleItems then
        Offset := Offset - VisibleItems
      else
        Offset := 0;
    end;
    scPageDown: begin
      if (MaxOffset - Offset) > VisibleItems then
        Offset := Offset + VisibleItems
      else
        Offset := MaxOffset;
    end;
    scPosition, scTrack: begin
      Offset := Trunc((ScrollPos / Scrollbar1.Max) * MaxOffset);
      Exit;
    end;
    scTop: begin
      Offset := 0;
      Exit;
    end;
    scBottom: begin
      Offset := MaxOffset;
      Exit;
    end;
    scEndScroll: begin
    end;
  end;
  ScrollPos := Trunc((Offset / ItemCount) * ScrollBar1.Max);
  ListView1.Refresh;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Note that you can use the scrollbar to access every single item, despite the fact that the scrollbar only has a min and max of 0 and 100 respectively - see the OnScroll processing.